# How do I change the class of several tds when hovering over one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here's my problem. I have a month-view type calendar in a table. In this calendar there can be certain periods which are (they have the class 'blocked'). The first date of such a period has the class 'blocked' as well as 'start', while the last date has the classes 'blocked' and 'end'.

**Now, when I hover over one of these TDs I want that td, and all the other ones in ONLY THAT SPECIFIC period (can be over multiple rows), to get the class 'blocked-highlight'.**

Here is a JSFiddle which generally shows what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/aoxmpouw/

Here is the Code from the Fiddle:

RELEVANT PART OF HTML:

```
        ...     
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td class="blocked start">17</td>
        <td class="blocked">18</td>
        <td class="blocked">19</td>
        <td class="blocked">20</td>
        <td class="blocked">21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="blocked">22</td>
        <td class="blocked">23</td>
        <td class="blocked end">24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        ...
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("td.blocked").hover(
        function() {
            $( this ).addClass('blocked-highlight')
        }, function() {
            $( this ).removeClass('blocked-highlight')
        }
    );
});
```

CSS:

```
.blocked {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

.start {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
}

.end {
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}

.blocked-highlight {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

JQuery is perfectly fine, as well as pure CSS solutions, if there are any.

Thanks in advance, Cheers -N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple periods / blocks and they are generated dynamically. give them a shared attribute or class.
Then you could do something like:

HTML:

```
   ...     
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td class="blocked start" rel="1">17</td>
    <td class="blocked" rel="1">18</td>
    <td class="blocked" rel="1">19</td>
    <td class="blocked" rel="1">20</td>
    <td class="blocked" rel="1">21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="blocked" rel="1">22</td>
    <td class="blocked" rel="1">23</td>
    <td class="blocked end" rel="1">24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    ...
```

JS:

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("td.blocked").hover(
       function() {
        rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $( "td[rel='"+rel+"']").addClass('blocked-highlight');
       }, function() {
        rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $( "td[rel='"+rel+"']").removeClass('blocked-highlight');            
       }
    );
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aoxmpouw/5/

Comment: This solution works great, thanks alot! I was wondering though if there was another way to do it only using jQuery selectors. Anyways, thanks again. Cheers, N

Comment: Your welcome! 
If you only want to use jQuery, you will have to loop trough each tr till you find the .blocked.end and highlight the .blocked divs while you are looping i suppose.

Comment: Oh I see. I implement the method above, works like a charm :)

Comment: this is not going to work for start and end dates range.

Comment: I'm using it in my application and I'm setting the 'rel' attribute to the period id. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `.siblings()` along with `.addBack()` to target sibling blocked and hovered element:

```
 $("td.blocked").hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).siblings('.blocked').addBack(".blocked").addClass('blocked-highlight')
    }, function() {
        $( this ).siblings('.blocked').addBack(".blocked").removeClass('blocked-highlight')
    }
);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/78Loy4nx/)**

Comment: This one is more appropiate because you might be using more calendars in one view. And this code highlights just the blocked elements in the hovered table.

Comment: this code does not highlight the period over multiple rows

Comment: this is very close to what i was looking for, the thing is it doesn't apply to the dates in the next row...

Comment: which all dates do you want to highlight on hover then

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aoxmpouw/2/ in this example there are two seperate periods. If i hover over any td in the first, only everything in the first one gets highlighted. If I hover over anything in the second block, only the ones in the second one get highlighted

Comment: It still doesn't consider that one period can have dates in different table rows.

Answer (score 0):

Is this wat you are expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/aoxmpouw/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("td.blocked").hover(
        function() {
            $('.blocked' ).addClass('blocked-highlight')
        }, function() {
            $('.blocked').removeClass('blocked-highlight')
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: this will happen for all his periods, there can be multiple periods in the same month

Comment: From the question, He wants to highlight all period even if in multiple rows having class blocked.

Comment: yeah, i only want the period hovered over to be highlighted. here's the issue http://jsfiddle.net/aoxmpouw/2/ if i have several. Then they all get highlighted

Comment: and a period is marked per `start`- and `end`-class. This is not considered in your code. It will highlight multiple periods if there are more then one

Answer (score 0):

```
i hope this will help you 

just replace your js like this

 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $("td.blocked").hover(
    function() {
        $("td.blocked").addClass('blocked-highlight')
    }, function() {
        $("td.blocked").removeClass('blocked-highlight')

      }
    );
 });
```

Comment: this will not consider the start and end of a period